# How to find points in a circle having specified Euclidean separations

Tags: geometry

I hope to find $4$ points in a circle. The side length constituted by those $4$ points is $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$ in order.  The image would be like this

[image]

I think the side length should be proportional to the central angle so I tried the following in *Mathematica*:

```
edgesLen = {1, 2, 3, 4};
angle = Accumulate[2 Pi Normalize[edgesLen, Total]];
rad = Sqrt[First[edgesLen]^2/(2 - 2 Cos[First[angle]])];
pts = Catenate[CirclePoints[{rad, #1}, 1] & /@ angle];
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, rad], PointSize[.02], Red, Point[pts], Black,
   Polygon[pts]}, Axes -> True]
```

I find the result is not right:

```
RotateRight[Developer`PartitionMap[Apply[N@*EuclideanDistance], pts, 2, 1, 1]]
```

> `{1.,1.90211,2.61803,3.07768}`

Is there any advice can give?

Comment: How can you have five points and only four lengths? Anyway, see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicQuadrilateral.html).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks,that is a typo.I have updated that.And If we want to find five points and five length,such as `{89, 90, 91, 92, 93}`.How to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what mathematical method you're using, and why you expect it to work?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think the length should be proportional to the  central angle.It's seem it not right.

Comment: The side lengths *cannot* be proportional to the angle, for simple geometrical reasons, as you can easily convince yourself with cases such as $\theta = \pi/2$ and $\pi$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks,that make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem! Solved it slightly differently. Defined angles `q1`, `q2`, and `q3` and radius `rr`. Wrote equations...

```
eqns={1 == 2*rr*Sin[q1/2],
      2 == 2 rr Sin[q2/2],
      3 == 2 rr Sin[q3/2],
      4 == 2 rr Sin[(2 π - q3 - q2 - q1)/2]}
(Reduce[eqns, {q1, q2, q3, rr}] // N) /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> 0}
```

Messy answer, but picked off for the angles and the radius

```
 (q1 == 0.504689 && q2 == 1.0457 && q3 == 1.69318 && rr == 2.0026)
```

Note the radius is not equal to 1. Converting to a set of points and plotting...

```
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, radius], Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts], 
          Blue, Line[AppendTo[pts, First[pts]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's the first way I tried too, but somehow didn't get a solution.  (I wonder why.)

Answer (score 5):

The side lengths certainly are *not* proportional to the angle.

Assume the circle is of radius 1 and the first point lies at $(1,0)$.  Then just write out all the components of the remaining three points and the distances ($a$, $2 a$, $3 a$ and $4 a$ for unknown $a$) and `Solve`.  Select the solution with $a>0$ (`#[[7,2] >0`) and the $x$ component of point 2 to be negative (`#[[2,2]]<0`) (or positive, if you wish) to ensure you don't get the trivial solution and to retain only one of the spatially symmetric solutions.

```
     mysolution = Select[
     Solve[{

(* points lie on unit circle *)

        x2x^2 + x2y^2 == 1, 
        x3x^2 + x3y^2 == 1, 
        x4x^2 + x4y^2 == 1,

(* distances are a, 2a, 3a, 4a *)

        (x2x - 1)^2 + x2y^2 == a^2, 
        (x3x - x2x)^2 + (x3y - x2y)^2 == 4 a^2, 
        (x4x - x3x)^2 + (x4y - x3y)^2 == 9 a^2, 
        (x4x - 1)^2 + x4y^2 == 16 a^2}, 

     {x2x, x2y, x3x, x3y, x4x, x4y, a}],
     #[[7, 2]] > 0 && #[[2, 2]] < 0 &][[1]];

    thepoints = Join[{{1, 0}}, 
    Partition[Drop[mysolution[[All, 2]], -1], 2]]
```

(*

{{1, 0},

{337/385, (76 Sqrt[6])/385},

{1/49, (20 Sqrt[6])/49},

{-(383/385), -((16 Sqrt[6])/385)}}

*)

```
  Graphics[{Circle[],
  Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[thepoints],
  Blue, Line[AppendTo[thepoints, First[thepoints]]]}]
```

[image]

In case you need it, the distances are found from:

```
Last@mysolution
```

a -> 4 Sqrt[6/385]

Answer (score 2):

```
w = 2 ArcSin[#/(2 r )] & /@ Range[4];
root = FindRoot[Total@w == 2 Pi, {r, 2}];
radius = r /. root;
pts[alpha_] := 
  radius FoldList[RotationMatrix[#2].#1 &, {Cos[alpha], Sin[alpha]}, 
    Most@w /. root];
txt[angle_] := 
  Text[Framed[Style[EuclideanDistance[##], 20], Background -> White], 
     Mean[{##}]] & @@@ Partition[pts[angle], 2, 1, 1];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, radius], PointSize[0.02], Red, 
   Point[pts[angle]], EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Black, 
   Polygon[pts[angle]], txt[angle], Dashed, Orange, 
   Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ pts[angle]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"radius=", radius}]], {angle, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]